# BeatsAudio Driver for Linux using laptop model HP Envy M6

Tags: audio

Back when I was on Windows 8, I installed the Beats Audio driver for Windows and everything sounded so clear and beautiful. I'm running Linux now (specifically Mint) but I wouldn't know how to install the Beats Audio driver for HP Envy M6.

Comment: In what format does the Beats Audio-driver come? `.deb`, `.rpm`, `.tar.gz`? Do you have a link to that driver (are you sure it exists?) Is it HP Envy M6 specific?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. Beats Audio doesn't say whether or not it's compatible with Linux. It's .exe but some people said "Go to the Linux community -- there's a way to configure it that the company won't tell you." So that's why I'm here.

Comment: With "the" in "install the Beats Audio driver" you let me believe there is one. Maybe you should explicitly ask if there is one in your updated question or what else you can do to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

This is supposedly for all HP laptops with Beats

1. Install hda-jack-retask from 
   [HD audio related stuff](https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/ubuntu/hda) . Download this small application according to your version of Ubuntu.
   After the completion of download, install the app.
2. After the app is installed, go to the terminal and type
   hda-jack-retask which opens the file. Open app using terminal
3. At the top, in codec section, select IDT 92HD91BXX codec.

   This code varies with various models. Check it
4. Check the “ Show unconnected pins” at the right side.
5. After this, you will see different types of unconnected pins of your
   sound driver. You have to map these pins to the right part of the
   beats audio drive. Care must be taken at this point.

   You can see there are various types of pins. We are not aware about
   these things. Even I don’t know what I am doing and is confusing. BUT do not worry at all.

   You just have to play on three pins. They are 0x0d , 0x0f and 0×10.
6. Go to the section having pin id : 0x0d .

   Change (Internal Speaker, Front side) to “Internal speaker (Back)”.
7. Go to the section having pin id: 0x0f.

   Change (Not connected) to “Internal speaker”. This part is about the
   under-display speakers.
8. Go to the section having pin id: 0×10.

   Change (Not connected) to “Internal speaker (LFE)”. This part is about
   the sub-woofer.
9. You are finally done with those pin settings. Apply it now. You can
   test with some sound. Check whether all the speakers are producing
   desired sound. The settings must be done as in following picture.

   Do as it is
10. If everything is all right, install boot override from the bottom
    right side and restart your device.

    Finally you must have sound with beats audio. Enjoy the sound and
    music. Also plug in the headphones, it must disable the external sound
    when the headphone is plugged in.

Check out [Is there a way to enable “beats audio” from within Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302340/is-there-a-way-to-enable-beats-audio-from-within-linux) for more details, which is also where I got it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry about that, I hope this is better.

Comment: I tried to correct your awful formatting, SE is not a typesetting system, but with a little bit of effort you can make things look acceptable, and at least not have empty lines in mid-sentence. More of a problem is that you refer in your text to "in following picture", but there is none. Please insert it or provide a link to the picture you are referring to.

Comment: sorry about that. I quoted something from the link and so used the quote option. And the "in following picture" I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: Of all the remaps enough to make one 0x10, effect is the same: beats working, but in mono mode, the left column will be silent. In general, certainly better than no beats.