# Sound (Beats Audio) problem on HP m6-1035dx Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, audio

Yesterday I installed Linux Mint (17.2) on my [HP Pavilion m6-1035dx](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03383025) and I'm experiencing problems with my sound.

The laptop has 2 speakers and a subwoofer (Beats audio). Only the right speaker works. I checked with the sound app (Sound test).

After exploring I found a [relevant article](http://www.linux.org/threads/beats-audio-on-linux.4443/) on linux.org about Beats Audio issues on similar laptops.

I downloaded the `HDA-jack-retask` tool and tried to override the ports. The setup in the article is the same as the setup [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177885/beatsaudio-driver-for-linux-using-laptop-model-hp-envy-m6) from unix.stackexchange and it did not work for me.

I run the command from the article:

```
wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh
```

and the output can be found [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=08ec24872687c0d03289678e2c52b032eec7b97e).

I don't know how to read the document. Any helps is appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, you previously had sound working on the system (e.g., under Windows) before installing Linux Mint?

Comment: Yes, it was working on Windows 7 ans 10

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but I killed pulseaudio not so gracefully on an Intel HDA laptop from HP and the card got stuck in an inconsistent state. I don't remember what it did to fix it, but even ALSA broke related to a pulse state problem. Just putting it out there that the problem might not be alsa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (for Ubuntu 14.04.4 but should work on Mint too) is:

To enable the subwoofer:
Install alsa-tools-gui.
Launch hdajackretask.
In the window that comes up, check “Show unconnected pins” in the upper right-hand side.
Scroll down and find “Pin ID: 0x10” and under that do the following:
Check the “Override” checkbox.
Select “Internal speaker (LFE)” in the pop-down menu
Click “Install boot override” button in the lower right-hand side.
Restart PC.

[Source](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RoEd6n53s-rpK8-jB_EHeAhZawNeOV1SXQL6rTIcwNg/edit#)